# How to share a connection just by command?

Tags: networking, network-programming, share, command-prompt, windows-7-x64

I want to share one of my connection (e.g. Local Area network) to another connection (e.g. Wireless Network Connection 4).

How can I do it in win7 64bit?

I dont what ICSmanager or another .Net library & I dont want win server, win XP or win7 32bit approach.

All thing I need is an approach by command (command prompt) in win7 64bit.

In other words, I need implement some parts of ICS by command. (parts of connection sharing not parts of start or stop ICS)

extra info:
In my project I want to creat a software like as connectify(Turn PC into to wifi hotspot).
I can set wlan configuration by command but I need implement sharing connection by command.
something like below link but not in wizard (just in command):

http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/internet-sharing-tethering/ht/how-to-share-internet-connection-on-windows7.htm

Thanks a lot.
Ya Ali.

Comment: It is still unclear exactly what you want.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I wrote extra information in the question

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is officially known as a "network bridge".  I don't know if there is a command line option to create a bridge, but you can create one in the Control Panel:

[Create a network bridge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
No. This is not network bridge. It`s called 'ICS'.
I want to implement ICS just by command in win7 64bit

Comment: Network Bridge and ICS are [two different things](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dbe21a25-8190-40db-bed2-fe87aa8984cf/network-bridge-and-ics). You said you *DON'T* want ICS, so that leaves Bridge.